# Invalid assignment of readonly type

Tags: typescript

I've stumbled upon something of which I'm not sure what's going on. Consider the following code:

```
interface T1 { value: number }
interface T2 { readonly value: number }

const t2: T2 = { value: 0 }
t2.value += 1
const t1: T1 = t2
t1.value += 1
```

Why can `t2` be assigned into `t1`? With TypeScript 3.7+ (probably also earlier versions, but I haven't tested) everything except `t2.value += 1` compiles. If `t2` really was readonly at runtime like below, this would cause a runtime error.

```
interface T { value: number }

const t2 = Object.freeze({ value: 0 })
const t1: T = t2
t1.value += 1
```

Comment: Related https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18770

Answer (score 0):

Here is the js code that corresponds to your first snippet:

```
var t2 = { value: 0 };
// t2.value += 1
var t1 = t2;
t1.value += 1;
```

And here is for the second one:

```
var t2 = Object.freeze({ value: 0 });
var t1 = t2;
t1.value += 1;
```

`Readonly` is used only used at compile time, but it gets lost when transpiling into js so no runtime error

U can make the assignment because you specified the type on `t1`. `t2` had the required properties for a correct assignment, but `value` in `T1` is not readonly.

Comment: t1 is not copy of t2, t1 is reference to same object t2 and it will give error. Object.freeze will make value property read only and even after assigning to other variable you cannot change it.

Comment: In the object.freze yes. I mean in the first example. Yeah, it's a reference, but I mean that it has the corresponding properties to be a valid assignment, regardless of that readonly modifier